# Post Content is not Displaying while using the next and the previous post.?

Tags: wordpress

```
    <?php if (is_single()) {?>
    <div class="post-prenex">
<div class="alignleft">
<?php previous_post('&laquo; &laquo; %',
 'Previous Post ', 'no'); ?>
</div>
<?php ?>
<div class="alignright">
<?php next_post('% &raquo; &raquo; ',
 'Next Post ', 'no'); ?>
</div>
</div> 

<?php }?>
```

Hi all I tried the simple plugin as the next and the previous post. In that next and the previous post are working fine . But the content in post is get disappeared. 
I don't know what i did the mistake. 
Note: I didn't edit the single.php file i tried by **add_action** of **the_content**

Any one Point out the problem and give a solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems that i see:

- previous_post() and next_post() are deprecated
- when working with the_content action, function must return actual content

Example

```
function mycontent( $content ) {
   $output = '';
   // add something to output
   return $content.$output;  //return content with output
}
add_action( 'the_content', 'mycontent' );
```

- Post/page navigation tags are template tags that should be used inside template files